# Regex With Lookahead For Fixed Length String

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds

```
strings = [
    r"C:\Photos\Selfies\1|",
    r"C:\HDPhotos\Landscapes\2|",
    r"C:\Filters\Pics\12345678|",
    r"C:\Filters\Pics2\00000000|",
    r"C:\Filters\Pics2\00000000|XAV7"
    ]
    
for string in strings:
    matchptrn = re.match(r"(?P<file_path>.*)(?!\d{8})", string)
    if matchptrn:
        print("FILE PATH = "+matchptrn.group('file_path'))
```

I am trying to get this regular expression with a lookahead to work the way I though it would. Examples of Look Aheads on most websites seem to be pretty basic string matches i.e. not matching 'bar' if it is preceded by a 'foo' as an example of a negative look behind.

My goal is to capture in the group `file_path` the actual file path only if the string does **NOT** have an 8 character length number in it just before the pipe symbol `|` and match anything after the pipe symbol in another group (something I haven't implemented here).

So in the above example it should match only the first two strings

```
C:\Photos\Selfies\1
C:\HDPhotos\Landscapes\2
```

In case of the last string

```
C:\Filters\Pics2\00000000|XAV7
```

I'd like to match `C:\Filters\Pics2\00000000` in `<file_path>` and match `XAV7`in another group named .
(This is something I can figure out on my own if I get some help with the negative look ahead)

Currently <file_path> matches everything, which makes sense since it is non-greedy (.*)
I want it to only capture if the last part of the string before the pipe symbol is NOT an 8 length character.

OUTPUT OF CODE SNIPPET PASTED BELOW

```
FILE PATH = C:\Photos\Selfies\1|
FILE PATH = C:\HDPhotos\Landscapes\2|
FILE PATH = C:\Filters\Pics\12345678|
FILE PATH = C:\Filters\Pics2\00000000|
FILE PATH = C:\Filters\Pics2\00000000|XAV7
```

Making this modification of `\\`

```
matchptrn = re.match(r"(?P<file_path>.*)\\(?!\d{8})", string)
if matchptrn:
    print("FILE PATH = "+matchptrn.group('file_path'))
```

makes things worse as the output is

```
FILE PATH = C:\Photos\Selfies
FILE PATH = C:\HDPhotos\Landscapes
FILE PATH = C:\Filters
FILE PATH = C:\Filters
FILE PATH = C:\Filters
```

Can someone please explain this as well ?

Comment: Does [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups?rq=1) give you the answer you are looking for

Comment: @itprorh66 unfortunately, no, I went though the answer but I guess I'm not smart enough to figure out what's wrong, I've tested several combinations through trial and error but none of them seem to work.

Comment: I hear you brother, I am no regex expert, so can't help.

Comment: I think I managed to figure this one out after reading a bit more --> (?![\\\:\w\d]+\\\d{8}\|.*)(?P<test>^.*)  I am still testing it so I could be dead wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
^(?!.*\\\d{8}\|$)(?P<file_path>.*)\|(?P<suffix>.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tk7XrZ/3).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?!.*\\\d{8}\|$)` - fail the match if the string contains `\` followed with eight digits and then `|` at the end of string
- `(?P<file_path>.*)` - Group "file_path": any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\|` - a pipe
- `(?P<suffix>.*)` - Group "sfuffix":  the rest of the string, any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FxDEzH):

```py
import re
strings = [
    r"C:\Photos\Selfies\1|",
    r"C:\HDPhotos\Landscapes\2|",
    r"C:\Filters\Pics\12345678|",
    r"C:\Filters\Pics2\00000000|",
    r"C:\Filters\Pics2\00000000|XAV7"
    ]
    
for string in strings:
    matchptrn = re.match(r"(?!.*\\\d{8}\|$)(?P<file_path>.*)\|(?P<suffix>.*)", string)
    if matchptrn:
        print("FILE PATH = {}, SUFFIX = {}".format(*matchptrn.groups()))
```

Output:

```py
FILE PATH = C:\Photos\Selfies\1, SUFFIX = 
FILE PATH = C:\HDPhotos\Landscapes\2, SUFFIX = 
FILE PATH = C:\Filters\Pics2\00000000, SUFFIX = XAV7
```